# Accuracy is not changing

Tags: keras, optimization, neural-network, dataset, loss

I tried to change learning rate, scaler(MinMax --> Standard), used SGD optimizer but the result is same. It is not changing from 72,44% of accuracy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOrKH.png)

Comment: Check if your input data has nan values?

Comment: The loss is not correct. It should be binary cross entropy.